# Pulseaudio set/check default source

Tags: linux, microphone, pulseaudio

So the **question** is,

1. How can I set the default source?
2. How can I list the current default source?

**Details**

I have 4 sound input sources on my linux device. Here is the result of `pactl list sources`:

```
1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.usb-Generic_Rmoncam_HD_720P_200901010001-02.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.usb-Generic_Rmoncam_HD_720P_200901010001-02.analog-stereo.2  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I tried to set the source *1 alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo* as my default source by several ways:

1.change /etc/pulse/client.conf, add following lines:

```
default-sink = alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo

default-source = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

2.change /etc/pulse/default.pa, add following lines:

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

After configuration complete, I tried `pulseaudio -D` and reboot the device, but the config take no effect. I don't know how to list the current default source and sink, so I use following command to verify:

```
$> pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=500
$> pactl list sources short | grep RUNNING
   3    alsa_input.usb-Generic_Rmoncam_HD_720P_200901010001-02.analog-stereo.2  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
```

The `pactl` still use my usb camera's microphone as its default source.

**System Info**

Linux kernel:

```
Linux D2-A109 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PulseAudio version:

```
$> pulseaudio --version
   11.1
```

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally..I find it's just caused by the microphone "unplugged"... And the way to set the default source is correct.

And I find the answer of Q2."How can I list the current default source?":

```
$> pacmd list-sources | grep -e 'index:' -e device.string -e 'name:' -e 'available'
* index: 1
name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    device.string = "front:0"
    analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
index: 2
name: <alsa_input.usb-Generic_Rmoncam_HD_720P_200901010001-02.analog-stereo>
    device.string = "plug:front:1"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
index: 3
name: <alsa_input.usb-Generic_Rmoncam_HD_720P_200901010001-02.analog-stereo.2>
    device.string = "plug:front:2"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
index: 7
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor>
    device.string = "0"
```

Corresponding to [PulseAudio wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_default_input_source), **The * in front of the index indicates the current default input.**

To avoid someone being stupit as me, we can determine if the microphone(source) is plugged, by checking '**available**' in the printing result of sources.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I list the current default source?

With pulseaudio 15.0 you can now just run `pactl get-default-source` to get the device string without resorting to running sed/awk/grep etc on the output.

Comment: 13.99.1 (from Ubuntu 20.04) also works with `pactl`

Comment: It doesn't though @ATorras . I'm also on Ubuntu 20 with version 13.99.1 and the get-default-source command doesn't exist for me

Comment: @Shardj: you're right, as it was included at 14.99.1 (https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/commit/src/utils/pactl.c?id=12fd4a909ad46edfaffdd41be40bd77b10d62a03).